# swap-windows tmux in list

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I have a bunch of tmux panes open and I would like to sort some of them from the list that I can bring up with `Ctrl-b "`.

In gnu-screen, I can move specific items up and down with the comma and semi-colon keys (IIRC). Is there something similar I can do in tmux other than lots of `swap-window -s s -t t`?

Comment: https://github.com/alexras/tmux-screnum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/alexras/tmux-screnum/ gives me almost what I need :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to script up the command and then launch it from a tmux shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

As 2020 from this [issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/656) you can change (alias swap, mov) windows by draging the tab with the mouse with :

```
bind-key -n MouseDrag1Status swap-window -d -t=
```